# compareTo cannot be applied to java.util.Date (Java)

Tags: java, compareto

I am writing an appointment program in Java and am coming across an error which is as follows :

```java
AppointmentNew.java:68: unreported exception java.text.ParseException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
        Date lowDate = sdf.parse(stdin.nextLine());
                                ^
AppointmentNew.java:70: unreported exception java.text.ParseException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
        Date highDate = sdf.parse(stdin.nextLine());  
                                 ^
AppointmentNew.java:77: unreported exception java.text.ParseException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
           Date newCurrentDate = sdf.parse(currentDate);
```

This program is suppose to allow the user to make new appointments, when they do that they are then able to input a date and description (they can do this as many times as they want), after that they can then pick a range of dates for the program to print out (it is suppose to print out the appointments in the date range they provided". This is where my error occurs...

Here is the code I have :

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class AppointmentNew 
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
  ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
  Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
  String choice = "";
  int choiceNum = 0;
  String date = "";
  String descrip = "";
  int type = 0;
  String typeChose = "";

  System.out.println("Welcome to Appointment App!\n");
  System.out.println("\t============================");

  do
  {
     System.out.print("\n\tMake Choice (1: New, 2: Print Range, 3: Print All, 4: Quit) ");
     choice = stdin.nextLine();
     choiceNum = Integer.parseInt(choice);

     if (choiceNum == 1)
     {
        System.out.print("\n\n\tEnter New Appointment Date in mm/dd/yyyy format: ");
        date = stdin.nextLine();

        System.out.print("\n\n\tEnter New Appointment Description: ");
        descrip = stdin.nextLine();

        System.out.print("\n\n\tEnter Type (1 = Once, 2 = Daily, 3 = Monthly): ");
        type = stdin.nextInt();
        stdin.nextLine();

        if (type == 1)
        {
           Once once = new Once(date, descrip);
           typeChose = "One-Time";
        }
        else if (type == 2)
        {
           Daily daily = new Daily(date, descrip);
           typeChose = "Daily";
        }
        else
        {
           Monthly monthly = new Monthly(date, descrip);
           typeChose = "Monthly";
        }
        String stringToAdd = "";
        stringToAdd = (date + " : \"" + descrip + "\", " + typeChose);
        list.add(stringToAdd);

        System.out.println("\n\n\tNew " + typeChose + " Appointment Added for " + date + "\n");
        System.out.println("\t============================\n");


     }

     if (choiceNum == 2)
     {
        System.out.print("\n\n\tEnter START Date in mm/dd/yyyy format: ");
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        Date lowDate = sdf.parse(stdin.nextLine());
        System.out.print("\n\n\tEnter END Date in mm/dd/yyyy format: ");
        Date highDate = sdf.parse(stdin.nextLine());  

        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        {
           int dateSpot = list.get(i).indexOf(" ");
           String currentDate = list.get(i);
           currentDate.substring(0, dateSpot);
           Date newCurrentDate = sdf.parse(currentDate); 

           if (newCurrentDate.compareTo(lowDate) >= 0 && newCurrentDate.compareTo(highDate) <= 0)
           {
              System.out.println("\n\t" + list.get(i));   
           }
        }
     }

     if (choiceNum == 3)
     {
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        {
           System.out.println("\n\t" + list.get(i));     
        }
     }

  }while (choiceNum != 4);      
 }
}
```

Comment: `Apple`s and `Orange`s...

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that you're trying to compare a *string* to a date. What does that even mean?

You should convert the `String` to a `Date` (e.g. with `SimpleDateFormat`) - or ideally, use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) - and then compare the values when you've got them both as the same type.

EDIT: As noted in comments, this isn't what you want either:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy");
```

`mm` means *minutes* in `SimpleDateFormat`, not *months*. You want `MM/dd/yyyy` instead. See the [`SimpleDateFormat` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more details.

Comment: so would "Date currentDate = sdf.parse(currentDateString);" work?

Comment: @user2213611: Yes - although your SimpleDateFormat pattern is incorrect at the moment (you want `MM/dd/yyyy` - `mm` means "minutes", not "months"). I'd still recommend using Joda Time though.

Comment: I just edited my code and added the new errors I am now getting.... Any suggestions?

Comment: @user2213611: Stack Overflow isn't an interactive debugging tool. Look at the errors, try to understand what they mean. Read a tutorial about exceptions if you don't know about them at the moment. Then work out what you want to do with the exceptions. Note that by changing the question you've made all the answers look very odd. I suggest you revert the question to its previous form, do some research and if you still can't work out what to do, ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

```
currentDate.compareTo(lowDate)
```

`currentDate` is `String` and `lowDate` is `Date`. You are trying `compareTo` on two different things.

Convert `currentDate` to Date object and then call `compareTo();`

Comment: so would "Date currentDate = sdf.parse(currentDateString);" work?

Comment: I just edited my code and added the new errors I am now getting.... Any suggestions?

Comment: @user2213611: Put your code in try/catch block (or) declare throws in method syntax. Exception message is very clear.

Comment: Can you provide some sort of example of a try/catch block? I have never done one of those before. I am fairly new to java actually.

Answer (score 1):

It is normal, you compare a object of Type Date with a String. Convert your String to a Date with your SimpleDateFormat (or with another format) and you will able to compare both objects.

```
Date correctCurrentDate = sdf.parse(currentDate);
```

To avoid to add try/catch in test program, I generally wrote the main method like :

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
```

Of course, for program that run in production, you should use try/catch where you can handle the exception. But it is annoying for a test program.

Comment: I just edited my code and added the new errors I am now getting.... Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes add a try/catch block or throws Exception : main (String[] args) throws Exception

Comment: I just tried both of those and still wasn't able to get it working correctly.  Could you please provide an example of the try/catch block and where it would go in my code?

Comment: This is what I did " try {Date lowDate = sdf.parse(stdin.nextLine()); } catch(ParseException e){}".